# latex cannot work within php exec()

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, latex, file-permissions

I am trying to call latex in PHP in Apache2 in Ubuntu10.04, like

```
$output  = exec("latex ".$filename, $return_var);
```

but it does not work, and outputs:

```
...
 [2] => ! I can't write on file `report.log'.
...
```

I can call file_put_contents() to write a file in that folder, also I have added myself to the group www-data.

Besides, I can use 'latex report.tex' as 'www-data' in a terminal; and PHP exec('whoami') returns 'www-data'. And, the permissions of that folder and report.tex are '777'.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you sure it can write to the directory where it tries to write the report.log? maybe try exec("cd /tmp; latex....")

Comment: yeah I am sure. But I have given up, and run this snippet in a real server. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happens when *report.log* file exists and was created by you as user. PHP natively have a own personal user in a system with name `_www` and when PHP starts execute `exec()` command, system have no permissions for `_www` to rewrite a log file.